# build docker image (centos) with volume with data for testing (postgresql)

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, centos

I want to make image with persisted data to other developers can run this container and use it. 
I use this https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/postgresql-96-centos7/ and do next step:
1) Run it with command

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRESQL_USER=svcg -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=svcg1 -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=bcs -p 5432:5432 --expose=5432 --name=postgres --net=docker-net -v psql:/var/lib/pgsql/data centos/postgresql-96-centos7
```

The result is a running container "postgres" and volume "psql".

2) Restore data from the dumpName.xml

```
java -jar database_backup_starter.jar -u svcg -p svcg1 -url jdbc:postgresql://192.168.99.100:5432/bcs -m restore -path database_dump
```

The volume "psql" contain the testing data.

Is it possible to do it in one step ? For instance to create image from the volume or from the docker with volume with data? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this image declares a `VOLUME` for the PostgreSQL data, you cannot make a derived image from this with prepopulated data in a volume, either using `docker build` or `docker commit`.  [It won't work](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes) (see the note "changing the volume within the Dockerfile").

The standard way to load data into a *newly created* database container seems to be to put a SQL-syntax database dump in the initialization directory when you start the container for the first time.  In this image, it looks like you'd have to wrap the database dump in a shell script and put it in an `/opt/app-root/src/postgresql-init/` directory.  For the [stock postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) you'd put a *.sql file in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`.